# How to instantiate models with DB connection

Tags: go, dependency-injection

Constraints:

1. not have everything in "main.go" but models and handler files for each request register_post.go (handler) user.go (models)
2. not use globals
3. use dependency injection for easy testing

Here is my code so far. It works if you only use one model. But how can I extend this to allow for another handler file and another model?

main.go

```
// Initalise Env with a models.BookModel instance (which in turn wraps
// the connection pool).
env := &handler.Env{
    Books: models.BookModel{DB: db},
}
// route call
v1.GET("/books", env.BooksIndex)
```

books_get.go handler

```
// // Initalise Env with a models.BookModel instance (which in turn wraps
// // the connection pool)

type Env struct {
    // Replace the reference to models.BookModel with an interface
    // describing its methods.
    Books interface {
        All() ([]models.Book, error)
    }
}



func (env *Env) BooksIndex(c echo.Context) error {


// Execute the SQL query by calling the All() method.
bks, err := env.Books.All()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return err
}
return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, bks)
```

}

books.go models

```
func (m BookModel) All() ([]Book, error) {
    // some body
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Зелёный How can i extend this to allow for another handler file and another model?